# SQL count records in from multiple tables Group by UsedID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some forms. It contains different usedId as a foreign key. One user has multiple forms. Now I want to see one user submitted how many forms.

I want the output:

**Login Id, FormName, NumberOfForms**

Shakil -> BurnOut -> 10

Shakil -> CIP -> 8

Shakil -> heating -> 20

But at first, I need the output. then decoration.

I'm trying multiple ways to solve it.

```
select  COUNT(*) as NumberOfForms  from Client_BurnOuts  b
inner join PatientPortalLogins l on l.PatientApplicationId = b.PatientApplicationId
where l.PatientApplicationId = 10
union all 

select COUNT(*) as NumberOfForms  from Client_EmergencyAssistances  b
inner join PatientPortalLogins l on l.PatientApplicationId = b.PatientApplicationId
where l.PatientApplicationId = 10
union all 

select COUNT(*) as NumberOfForms  from Client_DukeEnergyFoundations  b
inner join PatientPortalLogins l on l.PatientApplicationId = b.PatientApplicationId
where l.PatientApplicationId = 10
union all
 
select COUNT(*) as NumberOfForms  from Client_CIPEnergyCrisises  b
inner join PatientPortalLogins l on l.PatientApplicationId = b.PatientApplicationId
where l.PatientApplicationId = 10
;
```

Another ways

```
SELECT l.LoginID, 
COUNT(cb.PatientApplicationId) as BurnOuts  ,
COUNT(ea.PatientApplicationId) as EmergencyAssistances, 
COUNT(du.PatientApplicationId) as DukeEnergyFoundations, 
COUNT(cip.PatientApplicationId) as CIP
FROM PatientPortalLogins l

inner join Client_CIPEnergyCrisises cip ON cip.PatientApplicationId = l.PatientApplicationId
inner join Client_DukeEnergyFoundations du ON du.PatientApplicationId = l.PatientApplicationId 
inner join Client_EmergencyAssistances ea ON ea.PatientApplicationId = l.PatientApplicationId 
inner join Client_BurnOuts cb ON cb.PatientApplicationId = l.PatientApplicationId 
where l.PatientApplicationId = 10
GROUP BY l.LoginID, cip.PatientApplicationId, cb.PatientApplicationId;
```

But I can't get the proper results.
I have a total five tables, PatientPortalLogins table contains only the user name, usedId.....
And four tables contain the different values,
I just want to see which user submit how many pages.
Example used1 submit 2 Client_CIPEnergyCrisises forms, 1 EmergencyAssistances forms, 5 DukeEnergyFoundations forms

Comment: mysql is not the same product as sql server... please correct your tags

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results... as it stands we have no idea what your "proper results" are.

Comment: maybe, I'll remove it

Comment: Example used1 submit 2 Client_CIPEnergyCrisises forms, 1 EmergencyAssistances forms, 5 DukeEnergyFoundations forms

Comment: Please show, as tabular data, your sample data and desired results. Text descriptions are not a good way to try and explain data.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I can solve my problem. If you have multiple tables then we can use them.

```
select l.LoginID, 'Client_BurnOuts' as Client_BurnOuts,  COUNT(*) as NumberOfForms  
from Client_BurnOuts  b
inner join PatientPortalLogins l on l.PatientApplicationId = b.PatientApplicationId
where l.PatientApplicationId = 10
GROUP BY l.LoginID
union all 

select l.LoginID, 'Client_EmergencyAssistances' as Client_EmergencyAssistances,  COUNT(*) as NumberOfForms  
from Client_EmergencyAssistances  b
inner join PatientPortalLogins l on l.PatientApplicationId = b.PatientApplicationId
where l.PatientApplicationId = 10
GROUP BY l.LoginID
union all 

select l.LoginID, 'Client_DukeEnergyFoundations' as Client_DukeEnergyFoundations, COUNT(*) as NumberOfForms  
from Client_DukeEnergyFoundations  b
inner join PatientPortalLogins l on l.PatientApplicationId = b.PatientApplicationId
where l.PatientApplicationId = 10
GROUP BY l.LoginID
union all 

select l.LoginID, 'Client_CIPEnergyCrisises' as Client_CIPEnergyCrisises, COUNT(*) as NumberOfForms  
from Client_CIPEnergyCrisises  b
inner join PatientPortalLogins l on l.PatientApplicationId = b.PatientApplicationId
where l.PatientApplicationId = 10
GROUP BY l.LoginID
;
```